# Switch between open windows (not workspaces) with 3 finger swipe - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, touchpad, workspaces, multi-touch

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, and all multitouch gestures work well.

But

I'm looking for an option to **switch between *windows* by swiping 3 fingers left/right.** Basically, to activate the `alt+tab` or the `super+tab` keyboard shortcut functionality with a 3-finger swipe.

***Currently*, swiping 3 fingers left/right, switches *workspaces***.
I mainly use one workspace, so I'd like to switch between my open windows/applications and not workspaces.

Is there a way?

I tried to select in Settings->Multitaking->Application Switching->2nd option but that seems to have no effect.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried it but this extension my help:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4245/gesture-improvements/

```
Gesture Improvements by harshadgavali

• Switch windows from current workspace using 3-finger horizontal swipe
• Cyclic gestures between Desktop/Overview/AppGrid using 4 vertical swipe
• Switch app-pages using 3-finger swipe gesture on AppGrid
• Unmaximize/maximize/fullscreen/half-tiling using 3-finger vertical & horizontal gesture
• Optional minimize a window gesture
• Override 3-finger gesture with 4-finger for switching workspace
• Pinch to show desktop
• Application specific keyboard shortcut based hold-swipe gestures (e.g., navigating browser tabs)
• Configure speed of gestures
• Support for X11
```

Comment: Installed, seems to work! Now just need to find how to re-set different swipe settings that I liked, like the apps overview. Thanks (:

Comment: For anyone who wants the 3-figer swipe between windows, and also the activities-overview: after installing the suggested extension, you get the 3-fingers swipe and **swiping 4-fingers UP/DOWN will act like the default 3-fingers up/down of before the extension**